# Deactivate entire sheet selection after paste

Tags: vba, excel

I recently asked a question and received a great answer on this site, but I am now running into a different problem.  The code below works well for running through each workbook in a folder, copying a sheet's contents, and pasting those contents into a master workbook exactly how I would like:

```
Sub ConslidateWorkbooks()
'Code to pull sheets from multiple Excel files in one file directory
'into master "Consolidation" sheet.

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim wbName As String

With ActiveSheet
    Range("A1").Activate
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")
wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Do While Filename <> ""
    If Filename <> wbName Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            copyOrRefreshSheet ThisWorkbook, Sheet
        Next Sheet
        Workbooks(Filename).Saved = True
        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate
    End If
    Filename = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub



Sub copyOrRefreshSheet(destWb As Workbook, sourceWs As Worksheet)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = destWb.Worksheets(sourceWs.Name)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        sourceWs.Copy After:=destWb.Worksheets(destWb.Worksheets.Count)
    Else
        ws.Unprotect Password:="abc123"
        ws.Cells.ClearContents
        sourceWs.UsedRange.Copy
        ws.Range(sourceWs.UsedRange.Address).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
End Sub
```

The problem I am having now:  After the paste is completed, each sheet in the master workbook has all of its cells selected, as though I `Ctrl+A`'d the entire sheet.  I would like to get rid of this.  It is a small task which I tried to accomplish in the line `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate` within the `Do While ..` loop, but it has not worked for me.

**EDIT:**

I found a solution that works in this case.  I am not sure why this was necessary, because the comments and answers in this thread seem like they *should* work, but they did not.  I call this `sub` before I turn `screenupdating` to `True` in the main sub:

```
Sub selectA1()
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet

    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Sheet.Activate
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        Sheet.Range("A1").Select
    Next Sheet

    Worksheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

I realize this is more complicated than it should be, but it works for my purposes.

Comment: Of all that code, what's the relevant part? You could just do say `Cells(1,1).Select` right before `End Sub`, no?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  That would select the correct cell in the last sheet which is edited, but not for all of the others.

Comment: I believe you should avoid use of ActiveSheet, ActiveWorkbook unless you really need to use them.  Instead, define specific variables such as with this line of code: "Dim wk As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, r As Range" and then set them with lines such as "set sh = ActiveSheet", etc... I have found this to avoid a lot of confusion, especially when debugging code since the "ActiveWorkbook" could be either the one containing code or the one being manipulated, which can change during a debugging session. Hope that makes sense.  Anyway, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @TonyM, I have been trying to do that as I get more experience in VBA.  I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

In your copy sub, add in another code in the loop that will select a cell which should deactivate the total used range selection and just select the coded range.

```
Sub copyOrRefreshSheet(destWb As Workbook, sourceWs As Worksheet)
Dim ws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = destWb.Worksheets(sourceWs.Name)
On Error GoTo 0
If ws Is Nothing Then
    sourceWs.Copy After:=destWb.Worksheets(destWb.Worksheets.Count)
Else
    ws.Unprotect Password:="abc123"
    ws.Cells.ClearContents
    sourceWs.UsedRange.Copy
    ws.Range(sourceWs.UsedRange.Address).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
    ws.range("A1").select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I added `ws.range("A1").select` which should do as I described above.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, and am still receiving the classic "Select method of Range class failed".  I believe the macro is trying to select `A1` in the source worksheets, not the master workbook.